# Meld: associate file extension with language syntax highlighting

Tags: file-association, meld

I use [meld](http://meldmerge.org/) for graphical diff comparisons.

I would like to associate `.tpp` as a C++ source file for syntax highlighting purposes.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meld uses the Gnome project's [GtkSourceView](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView) component for syntax highlighting.

In order to change the file associations, edit the following file:

```
/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/cpp.lang
```

Edit the `"globs"` section under `language/metadata/property` and add `;*.tpp`

```
<property name="globs">*.cpp;*.cxx;*.cc;*.C;*.c++;*.tpp</property>
                                                 ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Is that still the case for Meld 3.18.0? Asking because `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/javascript.lang` lists `*.js;*.node` in the globs, yet Meld highlights `.mjs` files just fine.

Comment: I'm using Meld on Windows but found this question while looking for the same info. For Windows users, these files are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Meld\share\gtksourceview-3.0\language-specs` (for Meld 3.20.4).

Answer (score 3):

You can create custom lang files in

```
~/.local/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/
```

If the directory does not already exist, you can create it. Then copy the lang file you want to use as a template from

```
/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/
```